# How do you copy the phone value to a "PHONE" field after a primary contact lookup is made?

Tags: custom-object, cti

I have a custom object that has a primary contact lookup.  The Email and Phone populates but they are formula (text) once the contact is found.  I would like the phone to be copied or entered in a "PHONE" field so my "Click to Call" link will work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow rule with a corresponding field update. Set it to run when the record is created and every time it is edited. Set the criteria to fire on ischanged(your formula field). Create the second text field, and in the workflow field update, set the text field as the destination field, and the value of the formula field as the source field.